# Running Zeppelin on an external EC2 to connect to an Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I would like to share my experience setting up a zeppelin server on an EC2 and connect it to an EMR to leverage its computation power.

Zeppelin 0.7.3 is not compatible with spark 2.3.0 though when you setup an EMR through wizard option you can have both of them together. Here I want to download and install zeppelin 0.7.3 along with spark 2.2.1 to be able to connect it to EMR 5.11.0.

The main steps are documented in this link:
[Running an External Zeppelin Instance using S3 Backed Notebooks with Spark on Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-an-external-zeppelin-instance-using-s3-backed-notebooks-with-spark-on-amazon-emr/)

However, this tutorial is for an older version of zeppelin and spark which works fine but when it comes to newer versions of spark and zeppelin things are a little bit more tricky. I tried to follow the same steps for zeppelin 0.7.3 and spark 2.2.1 but when I tried `sc.version` in the zeppelin console I used to get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:398)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:387)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me several days to find the work around. The solution is to add the following lines in the zeppelin-env.sh file:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/ec2-user/spark
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/ec2-user/hadoopconf
export MASTER=yarn
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
```

Especially, the last line is the trick which defines the user under which zeppelin accesses hadoop on the EMR.

This is the same case for zeppelin 0.8.0 and spark 2.3.0.

I hope this was useful to someone! :)

Comment: Zepplin has many dependency issues of integrating  spark  with external 
 opensource apache projects eg.1.MongoDB connector for spark  2.connecting to spark to elastic-search which work perfectly in spark shell but not through Zeppelin.Anyway great work

Comment: Can we connect our local Zeppelin to EMR? do you know the configurations?